# Speakers make popping sound when on battery power. What should I do?

Tags: audio

I am running Linux Mint 11 on my notebook, which is basically a variation of Ubuntu. I have been hearing a popping noise in the speakers ever since I installed the OS, but just now realizing that the popping sound only happens on battery power. This noise is driving me insane and even happens when I mute the speakers. It sounds like: "pop" [30 sec pause] "pop pop". Please someone, anyone help me.

Notebook: HP Pavilion DV6325US
P/N: RV004UA
OS: Linux Mint 11 (with current updates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a side effect of sound chip powersaving (switching on and off). I experienced something similar when I misconfigured [tlp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP) (a power management tool), which switched the hda-intel chip off every couple of seconds

I am not sure where to configure similar options without tlp. Might depend on which powermanagement tools are in use.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I installed Linux Mint 12 and the problem is pretty much gone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is probably a quirk in ALSA's config. See here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto

You will probably need to tweak your config a bit, and the noise should go away. P.S. Try an Ubuntu Live CD if you can. If the problem does not occur there, then you know it's very specific to your installed system.

Comment: I am having a little bit of difficulty getting this correct. I'm following the instructions, but my Codec is not in the list like the examples are. My codec is Conexant CX20549 (Venice).

Comment: @ITman: I wouldn't call myself an alsa expert, but that's likely an hda-intel chip masked as something else. I would suggest reporting a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a Hp pavilion dv1000, with Linux Mint 13 LTS (xfce version).
 It was apparently solved by right clicking the batery icon next to the clock, selecting "Preferences", clicking the "on battery" options and removing the selection from the "... over performance" option (sorry, I'm using Mint's portuguese version and I'm not sure what's the english version of those options).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Archlinux (Last update July 2021) on a Lenovo Ideapad. The popping only happened when on battery, but in my case it happened even more frequently--like every 2 seconds. Anyway, I solved the problem by opening Pulse Audio Volume Control, Configuration tab and under Built-in Audio profile, I had to select "Analog Stereo Output" instead of "Analog Stereo Duplex".

Hope this helps somebody.